# Sql: Setting distinct for one value of one column

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, distinct

Is it possible to set it so that if you try to created a table where two values match and one value is a specific value say, 1, then it won't let you?

I want to have a table like this:

```
Table1_id: | Table1_name:
1          | Edgar
2          | Rudy

Table2_id: | Table2_Table1_id |Table2_active(bit):
1          | 1                | 1 (this is okay)
2          | 1                | 0 (this is okay)
3          | 1                | 1 (this is NOT okay) // shouldn't work
4          | 1                | 0 (this is still okay)
5          | 2                | 1 (this is okay)
6          | 2                | 0 (this is okay)
7          | 2                | 1 (this is NOT okay) // shouldn't work
8          | 2                | 0 (this is still okay)
```

I want to be able to have as many (x,0s) as I want but only be able to have ONE (x,1)
How could this be accomplished?

edit: possible solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER active_check BEFORE INSERT ON table2`
IF EXISTS (SELECT table2_id FROM table_2 WHERE table2_table1_id = NEW.table2_table1_id WHERE active = 1)
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN
END;
```

Would my use of `New.table2_table1_id` work here even though it's in its own statement? If not how could I get around that?

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: What would be better, IMHO, is to have a `Table2_ID` in `Table1` that indicates the active record. Because the above constraint would be hard to enforce.